# Java Documentation: What is meaning of 'methods inherited from interface X

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I must be missing some basic Java terminology here:

Classes can be extended, therefore their methods can be **inherited** by their sub-classes.

Interfaces can be **implemented**. An implementing class will have to implement all of the interface's methods - the interface itself does not implement anything, only declares.

So, how come when I look at the documentation of HashSet (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), I see a list of methods which are **inherited** from **interface** java.util.Set ?

Comment: you are missing the part that interfaces can extend another interfaces too

Comment: In Java >= 10 this might be called "Methods declared in", see https://stackoverflow.com/q/55938491 for the meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are referring to the statements like this from the generated JavaDoc HTML:

> Methods inherited from interface java.util.Set ...

Inheritance in this sense means that the signature of the methods in question is inherited, but not necessarily the implementation. The reason for that is simple: In Java you usually do not look into the implementations of third party code, but only into the interfaces with their signatures and JavaDoc.

So, basically, the signatures of those methods are inherited from interface `Set` and implemented in the `HashSet` or `AbstractSet`. Hence, actually it is implementing the interface `Set`.

---

**Sidenote**: In Java 8, you can have Interfaces implementing methods, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has more to do with the javadoc than with the language.  In Java, all the methods in the interface have to be implemented.  So from a language standpoint, there's no real difference betwen `add` and `addAll`.  Both are declared in `Set`; `HashSet` is a concrete class; therefore it must provide an implementation for both.

The difference really just has to do with whether the author had anything to add to the javadoc in the interface.  For `add`, it's necessary to add javadoc to `HashSet`, because `Set` defines `add` as an optional operation (it could be implemented by throwing an exception), therefore `HashSet` needs to specify that `add` actually does something useful.  For `addAll`, however, there's no need to add any documentation in `HashSet` that wasn't already in `Set`'s javadoc.

So I think that the javadoc page is slightly inaccurate; it really should say that the "javadoc" is inherited from `Set`, not the methods.  (Technically, the methods aren't inherited, because an abstract method from an interface isn't inherited if there's another method with the same signature--see [JLS 8.4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8).  That applies equally to *all* methods declared in the interface, whether or not the javadoc says they're "inherited".)  However, saying "Documentation inherited from class java.util.Set" might look a little odd to readers.  So I'm OK with a slight technical inaccuracy here if it conveys the message adequately.  Most readers wouldn't notice the inaccuracy, and it really doesn't matter.  In fact, I didn't notice this little flaw in the javadoc until you posted this question--and I'm someone who used to work on a compiler for a different language and spent many hours reading the language standard and delving into the exact definitions of the terms so that I could find out exactly what the standard required.