# Javadoc: Difference between "Methods inherited from" and "Methods declared in"

Tags: javadoc

The JDK Java docs for Java < 10 have a section called "Methods inherited from" which lists methods which are declared in the parent class / interface. However starting with Java 10 this section is called "Methods declared in".

For comparison:

- [Java 8: java.lang.Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#methods.inherited.from.class.java.lang.Object)
- [Java 12: java.lang.Number](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Number.html#methods.inherited.from.class.java.lang.Object)

Is there a difference between them or is this only a change of the section name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 10 the option [`--override-methods (detail|summary)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/javadoc.html#GUID-9D532574-1CDB-4D30-99F3-A308DCAEE55F__GUID-83C00666-981D-4D87-A45B-55B4F4E8011D), was added to the `javadoc` command:

- [Release notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/10-relnote-issues-4108729.html#JDK-8157000)
- [JDK-8157000](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8157000): Feature request
- [JDK-8187386](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187386): Tracking the addition to javadoc

The intention was to reduce the noise when methods are implemented or overridden, but the documentation remained unchanged.

## Modes

### `detail` mode (default)

The `detail` mode is the default when you use `javadoc` without specifying `override-methods`.

It behaves the way the documentation has been generated before:

- If a method is not overridden, it will be in the "Methods inherited from" section.
- If a method is overridden, it will be documented under "Method Detail", regardless of whether its signature or documentation was changed as well.

### `summary` mode

- If a method is overridden **and** its documentation is changed, it will be documented under "Method Detail".
- Otherwise it will be listed under "Methods declared in".

The `summary` mode is now used to generate the JDK documentation ([JDK-8189706](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189706)).

Be aware that this mode is currently bugged because it ignores some changes to the method signature which should be documented, see [JDK-8223607](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223607).

## Conclusion

You will either see a "Methods inherited from" or a "Methods declared in" section.
When comparing two documentations (one with "inherited from", the other with "declared in") for the same class, then the one with "inherited from" might list more methods under "Method Detail", while for the "declared in" one, some methods are instead in the "declared in" section.

So yes, there is a difference between them.

## Example

The difference in behavior can be seen for example for the `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit` class:

- [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#toString--): Listed under "Method Detail"
- [Java 12](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#methods.inherited.from.class.java.lang.Enum): Contained in "Methods declared in class java.lang.Enum"; see also the [source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/2af1bab5b4dd9b9f709693fd3a61587884d69b36/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.java#L277) to verify that the method is actually overridden